# Kafka Consumer: How to read specific Avro field in Python?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, avro, confluent-platform

In the below snippet of the consumer, I am able to receive the data sent. How do i access particular values from the entire data to work with.

```
from confluent_kafka import KafkaError
from confluent_kafka.avro import AvroConsumer
from confluent_kafka.avro.serializer import (SerializerError,
                                             KeySerializerError,
                                             ValueSerializerError)

***
***
***

c.subscribe(['Topic'])

while True:
    try:
        msg = c.poll(10)
        print(msg)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two ways you can achieve this:

```
msg.value()['myFieldName']
```

or

```
msg.value().get('myFieldName')
```

---

For instance,

```
c = AvroConsumer({
    'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092',
    'schema.registry.url': 'localhost:8081',
    'group.id': 'test-group'
})


c.subscribe(['Topic'])

while True:
    try:
        msg = c.poll(10)

        if msg:
            print(f"field1 Value: {msg.value()['field1']}")
            print(f"field2 Value: {msg.value().get('field2')}")

        else: 
            pass
    except SerializerError as e:
        print(f"Message deserialization failed for message {msg}:\n{e}")
```

Comment: And `get('myFieldName', 'default')`

Answer (score 1):

I see you're importing the AvroConsumer, so you would have

```
c.value()['field']
```